# How to align local coordinate with object?

Tags: transforms, coordinates, transform-orientation

I created hundreds of cylinders, joined them into a single object, then splitted back by `mesh -> separate -> by loose parts` in Edit mode. The splitted-back objects' local coordinates are not on their direction before join, especially they do not have an axis pointing to the cap. As a result I cannot move the cylinders easily in their local coordinates.

So is there any automatic way to rotate each coordinate **(not rotate the object)** to make them align with each cylinders' caps?

Comment: You can switch your *Transform Orientation* to *Normal*, but that may not pick a predictable axis.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to join and separate objects as a way to group and ungroup them. Especially if the objects to be joined have unique properties that you wish them to keep. The reason is that the final object in the selection sequence will become the active object before joining, and all the other objects will inherit all manner of properties from the active object after the join. Consider parenting instead. If you absolutely must rotate true coordinates without visually rotating the geometry, consider rotating in Object Mode, and then counter-rotating in Edit Mode.

Comment: I would upvote this as an answer @R-800